# If multiple players perform the same action, does it go faster?

Tags: monaco

When performing an action such as opening a safe or disabling an alarm, does it take less time when multiple players are involved?

Comment: I know it works for revives, but other stuff I'm not so sure about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's only faster when multiple players revive their teammate. Other actions, such as multiple people working on a lock, won't speed up the process. Every class does have their own advantages in completing actions:

- Lookout: Climbs up vents and staircases faster
- Locksmith: Unlocks safes and doors faster
- Hacker: Hacks computers and disables alarms faster
- Pickpocket: Jumps into bushes faster

There are a couple exceptions to these rules. If you've completed an action such as entering a vent, staircase, or bush, your teammate can enter into the same area without spending any "working-time" on it.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some general rules on the "clock dial" actions.  These are written from memory and experience and may contain minor errors.  It should be mostly correct, though.

- most actions take 3 seconds
- a character with proficiency reduces the time by a factor of 3.
- most actions can be done instantly with a wrench.
- extra characters doing the same action do not speed up the process.

Here are the actions that don't take 3 seconds by default:

- 1 second:

  - entering a bush or tree
  - breaking a jewel case (no "clock dial" is shown)
  - resetting a ringing telephone
  - putting on a disguise
  - opening a scanner "handprint" door under attack by a virus
  - opening an alarmed safe under attack by a virus
  - picking up an inventory item
- 4 seconds:

  - power switches
- 6 seconds:

  - reviving a teammate
  - getting into a sedan
  - getting into a helicopter
  - opening a security "double-locked" door
  - opening an ATM
  - opening a safe

Here's the list of proficiencies:

- Locksmith:

  - opening a locked door (including scanner "handprint" doors)
  - opening a security ("double-locked") door
  - unlocking an ATM
  - unlocking a safe
- Pickpocket:

  - entering a bush or tree
- Cleaner:

  - applying a medkit
- Lookout:

  - climbing a ladder
  - entering a window
  - climbing a staircase
- Mole:

  - breaking a jewel case
  - climbing through secret passages (no "clock dial" is shown)
- Gentleman:

  - putting on a disguise
  - getting into a vehicle
- Hacker:

  - putting a virus in an electrical outlet (note that no other classes can do this)
  - putting a virus in a computer
  - turning off an alarm
  - turning off a security device
- Redhead:

  - reviving a teammate

Here are the exceptions to the other rules:

- reviving a teammate cannot be done with a wrench.
- two teammates (without a Redhead) can revive a teammate in 3 seconds.
- three teammates (without a Redhead) can revive a teammate in 2 seconds, same as a single Redhead.
- two teammates (with a Redhead) can revive a teammate in 1 second.

I have not experimented with other configurations, such as three teammates with a Redhead or two Redheads.  I also have not experimented with using a wrench on most 1-second tasks; my reaction time is often not quite fast enough to tell if the wrench was used or not.  :)